# How to fire query in mysql? Can anyone explain addFieldToFilter?

Tags: magento-1.7

I have tried

```
$get_default_metal = Mage::getModel('custompricing/metaloptionsenabled')->getCollection()
->addFieldToFilter('product_id', $product_id)
->addFieldToFilter('store_id',0)
->addFieldToFilter('status',1)
->addFieldToFilter('isdefault',1)
->addFieldToSelect('metal_id')
->addFieldToSelect('ring_sizer')
->getFirstItem();
```

=>

```
$sql = "select metal_id,ring_sizer from metal_options_enabled where store_id=0 and status=1 and isdefault=1";
```

Is this right?

Comment: just use `echo $get_default_metal->getSelect()->__toString()` to print the query  of this collection

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function toString() on null - I am getting fatal error.

Comment: `echo $get_default_metal->getSelect();` will show you query

Comment: __toString() need

Comment: first remove `->getFirstItem();`   then use `$get_default_metal->getSelect()->__toString() ` and use `$get_default_metal->getFirstItem()` get first item data of collection

Comment: @Amit Bera thank you so much - query is getting printed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First remove `->getFirstItem();` then use `$get_default_metal->getSelect()->__toString()`  for print the query

and  the add  **$get_default_metal->getFirstItem()** get first item data of **collection**

Answer (score 0):

`getFirstItem();`  gives you only first row.

for Print  sql Query just write like this,

`echo  $get_default_metal->getSelect();`